# Buscar valores duplicados similares (LIKE) en una tabla de una base de datos MySQLi

Tags: base-de-datos, mysqli

estoy haciendo una sincronización de datos de alojamientos de una API externa y guardando los datos de cada alojamiento y su localización. Tengo una tabla Towns donde voy metiendo la ciudad o pueblo en la que se encuentra cada alojamiento y relacionándolos. El caso es que tras actualizar 10000 alojamientos, me estoy dando cuenta que no siempre viene el nombre de la ciudad de la misma manera y se me están duplicando las ciudades de esta manera:
 - Benalmádena
 - Benalmadena
 - Benalmádena-malaga
 - Benalmádena-ma
 - Benalmadena-malaga

El caso es que me gustaría hacer una consulta a esta tabla donde me saque los valores que contengan otro valor. Esto es, (WHERE name LIKE "%Benalmadena%") pero igual que Benalmadena, hacer esto con todos los valores de la tabla para buscar estas coincidencias.

¿Alguien me puede decir como hacer  esta consulta SQL?

Y por otro lado, ¿hay alguna manera de que al realizar una búsqueda en la tabla TOWNS para ver si el registro existe, no se tenga en cuenta la tilde?
**Lo he solucionado realizando una busqueda LIKE**

```
$town = $em->getRepository('App:Town')->createQueryBuilder('t')
->where('t.name like :name')
->setParameter('name', trim($twnN));
$town->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**EDIT:**

La estructura de mi tabla TOWNS es la siguiente:

ID: int | name: string | lat: string | long: string

Y la estructura de mi trabla Accommodations es:
ID:int | name: string | town_id: int

Estos son algunos de los registros duplicados del campo "name" de mi tabla Towns:

> - Benalmádena
> - Benalmadena
> - Benalmádena-malaga
> - Benalmádena-ma
> - Benalmadena-malaga

Lo que me gustaría es recorrer cada uno de los registros de esta tabla y buscar registros que contengan este string. 
Por ejemplo si cojo todos los registros en una variable $towns y hago un foreach la SQL sería así:

```
$towns = $this->getAllTowns();
foreach($towns as $k => $t){
  $sql = "Select * FROM TOWN WHERE name like '%".$t->getName()."%'";
}
```

Por cada registro, obtengo todos los registros que contienen esta palabra. 
No se si esto es posible con una consulta MySQLi.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Seguramente alguien te lo pueda detallar mejor, pero puedes hacer el like con la palabra clave collate para que el like sepa que estás buscando en español e ignore las eñes, tildes etc. Más info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: Muchas gracias @ordago, con esto resuelvo una de mis dudas. Haber si alguien me puede ayudar con la otra consulta. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Pretendes desarrollar un algoritmo que detecte nombres similares de ciudades o algún tipo de combinación con su provincia? Para concretar un poco la pregunta, por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agregar la estructura y `collation` de la tabla `Towns`. También sería útil si pudieras incluir las consultas que has intentado.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por contestar. @DavidJP, no pretendo desarrollar ningún algoritmo complejo, simplemente quiero realizar esta consulta en mi base de datos para saber qué ciudades están duplicadas con un nombre similar. 
Por otro lado al final no he utilizado collation ya que con Doctrine 2 al hacer la consulta con "LIKE", ahora me saca los registros con y sin tilde.
He editado la pregunta para añadir más información, no tiene mucho mas, solo quiero saber como hacer esta consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En respuesta a:

> ¿hay alguna manera de que al realizar una búsqueda en la tabla TOWNS para ver si el registro existe, no se tenga en cuenta la tilde?

Podrias usar [`presentadores del juego de caracteres`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-introducer.html) junto con [`COLLATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html)

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM Towns
WHERE name LIKE _utf8'%Benalmádena%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4afdb4/15)</kbd>

---

En respuesta a:

> me gustaría hacer una consulta a esta tabla donde me saque los valores que contengan otro valor. Esto es, (WHERE name LIKE "%Benalmadena%") pero igual que Benalmadena, hacer esto con todos los valores de la tabla para buscar estas coincidencias.

Podías usar [`EXISTS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) para buscar si existe al menos un registro distinto de si mismo y con un nombre similiar.

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Towns AS T
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT A.id 
    FROM Towns AS A
    WHERE A.id != T.id 
      AND A.name LIKE CONCAT('%', CONVERT(T.name USING utf8), '%')
    LIMIT 1
  );
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4afdb4/17)</kbd>

---

### Referencias:

- [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [`CONVERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos, esto es exactamente lo que buscaba.